# Is Tomahawk12 tld valid?

Tags: jsf, tomahawk

I'm using **Tomahawk12-1.1.10** with **Mojarra JSF 1.2_04**.

When I try to use:

```
<t:dataList id="someId" rowKey="key" var="item" value="#{myBean.listOfItems}">
     <t:selectBooleanCheckbox id="" .../>
</t:dataList>
```

I am getting the following error:

> Attribute rowKey invalid for tag
>   dataList according to TLD

In [t:dataList](http://myfaces.apache.org/tomahawk-project/tomahawk12/tagdoc/t_dataList.html) documentation there is an **rowKey** attribute, but in tld file there is no mentions of such attribute. Is it possible that tld file in official distribution is outdated?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"rowKey" is a new feature available since tomahawk 1.1.11. It is now available and can be downloaded from [MyFaces Tomahawk Download Page](http://myfaces.apache.org/tomahawk/download.html)